# Hiren's Boot CD - HDD Diagnostics

Tags: hard-drive, diagnostic

I have a bunch of hard drives which I want to sell, so am wiping them using [Hiren's Boot CD](http://www.hiren.info/pages/bootcd). I want to check that the drives are healthy first. Can anyone recommend a tool for this? There are several manufacturer ones on there, but are they specific to that brand?

What should I be looking out for? Is it the SMART monitoring?

Also, how do I access them from the disk on bootup?

Thanks!

Comment: +1 for doing the right thing before selling them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I recommend using MHDD 4.6 (Also does mechanical check) or SmartUDM 2.00. If your drives support SMART, then you should be able to read their state from either of these programs. The should be in DOS tools, under Hard Disk Tools.

**EDIT:**
And yes, most brand-specific tools will only work with their own branded hardware.

Comment: Thanks for the update on that - worth knowing for the future!

Comment: @Mark You're very welcome! Only just saw that part on your question! ;)

Answer (score 0):

If the system you are trying the drives out on has SMART, you can check the status with various utilities on the CD. Check out the Hiren's page and do a search (case-sensitive) for SMART: http://www.hiren.info/pages/bootcd.

Comment: Some are spelled as S.M.A.R.T.

Comment: All titles that contain S.M.A.R.T also have it spelled as SMART somewhere in the description.