# Using MHDD 4.6 to check hard drives

Tags: hard-drive, smart, diagnostic

Following on from my [previous post](https://superuser.com/questions/228328/hirens-boot-cd-hdd-diagnostics), I have run MHDD 4.6 from Hiren's Boot CD.

1) Does anyone know which commands I should be running to check the health of a drive?

2) I have run 'scan', but about 1/3 of blocks show up as a red X. Does this mean the drive is dead, or can it be recovered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Various discussion of "red" blocks here, http://forum.hddguru.com/hdd-faq-t5.html