# Windows 10 Stuck At Spinning Circles

Tags: hard-drive, boot, windows-10

My computer will not boot, it gets to the Win10 loading screen and the circles just spin and windows never fully loads.  I connected the drive via USB and ran `diskpart` to get some basic info off the drive and this is what I got.

```
Disk###     Status     Size     Free     Dyn     Gpt
Disk 1      Online     931 GB   0GB
```

What do I need to do in order to get this drive to boot?

**EDIT**
From the comment by @SuperSoph_WD - I have tested the WD drive, and it is in good health with no issues.  I can also use a Boot CD to boot into an XP environment, and see my file structure and I ran `chkdsk` and reported no errors as well.

However, upon reboot and attempting to boot from the drive itself, the drive will still just provide the spinning circles and never actually boot into the Windows 10 environment.

Comment: I'd recommend you to test the HDD using its brand-specific [diagnostic tool](http://superuser.com/questions/520780/tool-to-test-hdd-for-health). This utility will help you determine the health and SMART status of the drive. If you don't have access to another computer from where you can test the drive through Windows. I'd advise you to download and create a bootable flash drive with [a DOS version of such a diagnostic software](http://superuser.com/questions/228328/hirens-boot-cd-hdd-diagnostics). It will allow you to test the HDD from your computer without booting into the OS. Hope it helps.

Comment: @SuperSoph_WD - see edit.

Comment: Good job with the troubleshooting! As a last resort, maybe you should also [try resetting BIOS](http://www.wikihow.com/Reset-Your-BIOS). This will get your BIOS settings back to factory defaults. Since your WD drive seems to be completely fine and working properly, then you  should also probably [clean installing Windows 10](http://www.howtogeek.com/224342/how-to-clean-install-windows-10/). I believe that your problem is coming from the operating system itself, rather than any component. Keep me posted, though! Good luck!